# Player bounds implementation and code review

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine, optimization

I need your help in review my code and give me some advices if i can improve it somehow.

I'm following unity course and the guy did this script to check bounds:

```
if(transform.position.x < -boundRange)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(-boundRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
if(transform.position.x > boundRange)
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(boundRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

A found a bit different way to achieve the same thing with only one if statement like that:

```
if(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x) + .1 > boundRange)
    transform.position = new Vector3(
        transform.position.x / Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x) * boundRange, transform.position.y, transform.position.z
    );
```

And i want to understand which way is better and why and give me some more recommendations about good practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not worry very much about that. There are lots of ways to do the simpliest things in programming. For example, applying to your case, for the abs value:

```
a = System.Math.Math.Abs(f);
a = UnityEngine.Mathf.Abs(f);
a = Unity.Mathematics.math.abs(f);
if (f >= 0) a = f; else a = -f;
a = f >= 0 ? f : -f;
```

You need to find the one that is more readable + understandable + standard to make the code easy to understand for you and your team. If you are in and `Update()` you might want to take also some performance consideration, but at the beginning I would not worry much about that also.
For your particular case I find the first snippet more readable, and in the second if x = 0 you're going to have problems.
I would take more care in the architechture approaches of your app, and the unity component approach also, to make thinks according to unity's philosophy than caring to make any small deatail the best way. Then the more you code, the more you will be taking care of the details without realizing.
Hope that makes sense!